# Manipulação de Stream(java 8)

Tags: java, java-8, stream

Bom dia pessoal gostaria que me tirassem uma pequena dúvida, tenho uma Stream de String com muitas linhas de um txt, preciso fazer um split para quebrar as linhas nos pipes, porém o retorno como sabem é um vetor de String, resumindo gostaria de saber se é possível chegar a isso:

```
Stream<String> linhas=Files.lines(caminho,StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
/**Alguma coisa aqui...**/
Stream<String[]> linhasSemPipe;//Resultado
```

Manipulando apenas as Streams, sem converção para outro tipo.

Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Mostre o conteúdo do arquivo de entrada e de saída que você espera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método `map`.

```
Stream<String[]> linhasSemPipe =  Files.lines(caminho,StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
                                       .map(linha -> linha.split("\\|"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar algo assim, retornando um `Stream`:

```
Stream<String> linesByPipe = 
   Files.lines(caminho)
        .map(line -> line.split("\\|")) // Quebra por '|'
```

Ou assim, retornando um `List`:

```
List<String> linesByPipe = 
   Files.lines(caminho)
        .map(line -> line.split("\\|")) // Quebra por '|' 
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```